# Scanner の使用時にエラー: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java

Javaでscannerを使用するときに以下のエラーがatCoderで実行するときに出てしまいます。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

**現状のコード:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ABC086C {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int[] location = {0,0};
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int x1 = 0;
        int x2 = 0;
        for(int i= 0; i<n;i++) {
            int t = sc.nextInt();
            x1 = sc.nextInt();
            x2 = sc.nextInt();
            location[0]=0;
            location[1]=0;
            for(int j = 1;j<=t;j++) {
                if(location[0]<x1&&location[1]<x2) {
                    location[0]+=1;
                }else if(location[0]<x1&&location[1]==x2) {
                    location[0]+=1;
                }else if(location[0]<x1&&location[1]>x2) {
                    location[0]+=1;
                }else if(location[0]>x1&&location[1]<x2) {
                location[1]+=1;
                }else if(location[0]>x1&&location[1]==x2) {
                    location[0]-=1;
                }else if(location[0]>x1&&location[1]>x2){
                    location[0]-=1;
                }else if(location[0]==x1&&location[1]<x2){
                    location[1]+=1;
                }else if(location[0]==x1&&location[1]==x2){
                    location[0]-=1;
                }else if(location[0]==x1&&location[1]>x2){
                    location[1]-=1;
                }
            }
            if(location[0]==x1&&location[1]==x2) {
                System.out.println("Yes");
            }else {
                System.out.println("No");
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: マルチポスト： https://teratail.com/questions/n9ldd9tutlnlve

Answer (score 0):

"atCoderで実行するとき" が具体的にどうしたときなのか分かりませんが、 `NoSuchElementException` は [`nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) で入力が無くなったため発生していると思われます。

例えば、質問文中のコードをターミナルで実行し、<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>でEOF送信すると該当の例外が送出されます。